# How to work with large files in python?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, python-2.7, large-data

I'm curiuos how to work with large files in python?

For example I have dataset on hard drive ~20Gb (just array of numbers) and I want to sort this array to get k min values.
So dataset can't be load into memory(RAM).

I think algorithm should be: load dataset by n chunks, find k min in chunk, store k min in memory and process every chunk, so we get k*n values and then sort them to get k min values.

But the question is how to store dataset(what format?), what is the fastest method to load it from disk(what size of chunk I must choose for particular hardware?)Maybe it can be done by using several threads?

Comment: What kinds of limits are there on these numbers? Is there some upper/lower bound? This will affect the sorts of approaches you might use.

Comment: Have your read http://neopythonic.blogspot.de/2008/10/sorting-million-32-bit-integers-in-2mb.html ? Can you provide more details about your specific task, dataset etc.?

Comment: You should use [`heapq.nsmallest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) on a lazy iterator over your data.  No need to get the k smallest values for each chunk -- you can get your result on the fly in a single pass.

Comment: For the more general questions, use [PyTables](http://pytables.org/).

Comment: @DonaghHatton I use int32 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need `external sort` instead. If you load everything into memory and sort them, it is named `internal sort`. In database, it uses `external sort` to do sorting task.

Maybe the following resources would help you.

- [Wiki, external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)
- [Wiki, internal sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_sort)
- [Github, external-sort](https://github.com/spiralout/external-sort)
- [A blog post about external-sort](http://www.umbrant.com/blog/2011/external_sorting.html)

  - [The author provides a github link about his work](https://github.com/umbrant/extsort)